# MySQL: dump using mysqldump.exe contains errors

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm dumping a table using *mysqldump*. Unfortunately the dumped SQL contains errors.

The first error I encountered was that MySQL didn't like mysqldump's use of `DELIMITER`. I read somewhere that these are extraneous so I tried semi-manually removing those and then found the next error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ';  /*!50003 SET sql_mode              =
>   @saved_sql_mode */' at line 1

The dump itself is 375 lines so I won't paste it all here, but this appears to be the line in question - this line appears twice in the SQL dump:

```
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
```

This table also contains a trigger, and I've read (for example, [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/11/unexpected-problem-with-triggers-and-mysqldump/)) that MySQL doesn't like these dumped/generated triggers. However, that referenced webpage is over a year old, and I'm using the most current version of MySQL and mysqldump.exe - v5.6.16.

Note that I'm **not** dumping the table with data.

Can anyone explain a way around this problem? Is it trigger-related? Does it have anything to do with the specifics of our table or does mysqldump.exe contain *imperfections*?

I don't want to be manually editing the files because this dumping process forms part of our unit tests - we're dumping the DB (only some tables dumped with data) into a test DB as part of an automated process.

Comment: Could you paste a few lines of your dump surrounding the faulty row here please?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Are you trying to import the dump (taken from a server running version 5.6) into a server running version 5.5 by any chance?

Comment: Nope. Not only is he DB definitely 5.6, but I'm not taking from a server to a local: both DBs are local; they're simply different schemas running in the same MySQL instance.